# cucumber @no-txn tag makes scenario skipped

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm having trouble running simple cucumber scenario without the transactional fixtures. When I tag a scenario with @no-txn or set Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures to false the scenario I want to run just gets entirely skipped, setting verbose output does not indicate what went wrong. Any ideas on how to fix this?